# fgets where the number of char read is bigger than the size of the storage

Tags: c, fgets

I'm looking at a code to learn things and I saw something like this :

```
void funRead(){
     char str[80];
     FILE *fi;
     fi = fopen("file","r");
     while(!feof(fi)){
        fgets(str, 200, fi);
        // do things
     }
     fclose(fi);
}
```

And it works! (It's quite a big code) I didn't understand why it was working so I tried to reproduce it (just this part, pretty much just the code above) and my program crashes (I'm doing it on **Eclipse**). It only works when I write

```
fgets(str, 80, fi);
```

Or another number < 80, otherwise it won't work.

Did I miss something?

**EDIT** : Screen capture of the part of the program I'm talking about
https://gyazo.com/c8847ccc36bbbe7a406a3260db8dd358
**Lines 4 & 26**

Comment: You missed the `feof`, [which is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941). But you are correct that the second argument to `fgets` needs to be less than or equal to the buffer size.

Comment: It works _only_ because the _actual_ length of the lines read is 79 [or less]. The `200` is the maximum (wrong), but if all lines are 79, you squeak by. (e.g.) If you had a line that is 90, the program will have undefined behavior [and will probably segfault]. You'd overwrite the return address of the function and may destroy the value of `fi` while reading.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, copy & paste code in your question.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. The fact that the other code "works" doesn't mean anything, it might run without crashing but it doesn't mean that it is running correctly. You just got lucky that you didn't see a segfault right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets(str, 200, fi);` is indeed wrong, because it is telling `fgets` to read up
to 199 characters when in reality `str` can store up to 79 characters (not
including the `'\0'`-terminating byte), that's why it "works"<sup>1</sup> with `fgets(str, 80, fi);`.

In general it's a good idea to use `sizeof` like this<sup>2</sup>:

```
char str[80];
fgets(str, sizeof str, fi);
```

With `sizeof` you will get the correct size, even if you later decide to change
the size of `str`.

One thing that is [really wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) is:

```
while(!feof(fi))
{
    ...
}
```

What the code should do is:

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fi))
{
    // do things
}
```

that's the proper way to read the whole file.

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>I put works in quotes because the way the code checks when to stop
reading is incorrect. However `fgets(str, 80, fi)` is the correct call.

<sup>2</sup>Note that `sizeof` will give the correct size only if `str` is an
array. If it is a pointer and you allocated memory for it, then you cannot use
`sizeof`, for example:

```
size_t len = 80;
char *str = malloc(len);
if(str == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}

fgets(str, len, fi); // <-- do not use sizeof here, but the variable
```

Comment: First, thanks for all those explanations. Actually I was trying to figure out why the 'wrong' code I wrote was working, because yes I understand how the code **should** work

Comment: @PaulMonties classic undefined behaviour. You just got lucky that it didn't crash right away. But it could have.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are defining a character array with size of 80 characters

```
char str[80];
```

```
fgets(str, 200, fi);
```

Above statement means that it is reading **200** characters from file "**fi**" in the character array "**str**" of size **80**.
You cannot copy 200 characters in an array of size 80.

Either make character array bigger or read 80 or less characters at a time from the file.

EDIT: The reason program crashes is because it is accessing **illegal memory locations**. This does not mean it will necessary crash if you index a location which is greater than size of array, It just means it can crash if it is not allowed to access that memory location.
So that is the reason, the code you mentioned is probably working(purely on chance), although that 200 part is wrong. If it ran then run it multiple times it will probably crash atleast once.

Comment: Yes I know that and I understand it, but I have a code under my eyes where there is pretty much the code I wrote and it works, that's what I dont understand. Is there any way?